# Typescript renaming keys in array without hardcoding?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two arrays. 1 with a list of titles the other with a list of names that will match these titles.

```
titleList
0: "CEO"
1: "CIO"
2: "CFO"
3: "CTO"

names
0: null
1: null
2: "James Dean"
3: null

0: "Paula Dean"
1: null
2: null
3: null
```

How can I rename the keys to the names of CIO, CTO etc so it looks like this

```
CEO: "Paula Dean"
CIO: null
CFO: null
CTO: null

CEO: null
CIO: null
CFO: "James Dean"
CTO: null
```

I have tried

```
 const t = resources['titles'];
    const rows = resources['names'];   
    const map = rows;   
    const filteredList: any[] = [];
    const MAP = skills;
    for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
      const object = rows[i];
      for (const key in object) {       
          if (MAP[key] !== null) {        
          object[MAP[key]] = object[key];
        }
          delete object[key];        
      }
      filteredList.push(object);
    }
    return filteredList;
  }
```

Comment: Could you please show the real data instead of that pseudo datastructure?

Comment: You call it an 'object' but... is it an array? What would the json look like? `titleList = ['CEO','CIO','CFO','CTO']`?

Comment: @TKoL yes it is an array. They both are arrays

Comment: is this an external requirement/input (2 arrays of strings)? if not, i would consider changing it to a an array of objects. parallel collections is an antipattern and might bite you later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a guess at what your data structure looks like but here is code to create an object with the appropriate keys from `titles` matching the values from `rows`; I assumed you wanted typescript because of your `typescript` tag.

```
const resources = {
    titles: [ "CEO", "CIO", "CFO", "CTO"],
    names: [null, null, "James Dean", null]
};

const titles = resources['titles'];
const rows = resources['names'];   

const map: { [key: string]: string | null } = {};
titles.forEach((item, index) => map[item!] = rows[index]);
```

`map` should now be object similar to:

```
{
    CEO: null,
    CIO: null,
    CFO: "James Dean",
    CTO: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With foreach you can do something like:

```js
const titles: string[] = [ "CEO", "CIO", "CFO", "CTO"];
const names: (string|null)[] =  [null, null, "James Dean", null];

const result: any = {};
titles.forEach((title: string, i: number) => {
    result[title] = names[i];
});

console.log(result);
```

or you can also use **reduce** like:

```js
const titles: string[] = [ "CEO", "CIO", "CFO", "CTO"];
const names: (string|null)[] =  [null, null, "James Dean", null];

const result = titles.reduce((objToReturn: any, title: string, i) => {
    objToReturn[title] = names[i];
    return objToReturn;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Hope this helps :)